# Can hard drive stepper motor can be used for making drones?

Tags: stepper-motor, hard-drive, drone

I have some useful hard drive stepper motor can it be used for making drone??

Comment: Speed vs airflow vs weight vs power requirements. But sure, why not?

Comment: Have you looked at any speed-vs-torque curves for stepper motors? You'll probably be rather disappointed.

Answer (score 3):

The **spindle motor** in a HDD is a BLDC (Brushless DC) motor that runs at ~5K-15K RPM so it could conceivably be used to drive blades on something like a quadracopter. You would need a controller to produce the proper waveforms (the hobbyists call it an ESC).

Most hard drives these days do not use stepping motors (too slow) to position the heads- they use voice coils. If it's got a stepper it must be ancient.

Edit: [Here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=TTu-AXrsJhA) is an attempt with 3 out of 4 motors - maybe marginally possible.

Answer (score 3):

I assume what you're referring to is actually the brushless spindle motor on the hard disk. This is not technically a "stepper motor", as it cannot hold a specific position.

If so: definitely not. Hard drive spindle motors are not particularly strong. The vast majority of their life is spent running at a constant speed under virtually no load; the most load they ever have to deal with is the inertia of the platters for a few seconds during spinup. Most hard drive motors run on a couple of watts of power at most.

The motors in a multirotor aircraft, by contrast, run at wildly varying speeds, and are expected to provide a *lot* of power (often hundreds of watts) whenever they're in use. This is a completely different application from a hard drive spindle motor, and it's extremely unlikely that the two types of motors would be interchangeable.

Comment: Indeed.  Though re-engineering CD-ROM motors (new magnets and windings) used to be a thing before there were as many purpose built R/C aircraft motors available.